# Using Ajax / custome JS to dynamically update states_list(), based on choice from countries_list() in same question?

Tags: javascript, ajax, docassemble

I have two questions earlier in my interview, that work great together.

Essentially, the first question presents a list of countries, using the very amazing and highly useful [countries_list()](https://docassemble.org/docs/functions.html#countries_list) function. The second question then presents a combobox of potential states using the (also) very amazing and highly useful [states_list()](https://docassemble.org/docs/functions.html#states_list) function, but modified to only show the states that might apply to the user, and modifies the label "State" as appropriate (and I have some other code that skips this question if there is only one state in the country (eg. Singapore) ).

```
---
question: |
  What country do you live in?
fields:
 - Country: jurisdiction.country
   input type: combobox
   code: countries_list()
---
question: |
  What state do you live in?
fields:
 - ${ subdivision_type(jurisdiction.country) }: jurisdiction.state
   input type: combobox
   code: states_list(jurisdiction.country)
---
```

What I'm wondering, is if there's a known way to accomplish this same effect "live" on a page using `input type: ajax` ([as here](https://docassemble.org/docs/fields.html#ajax)), custom JS, or some other method?

Ideally, I could "live reload" the question prompt with `subdivision_type()` as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a similar example in the docassemble documentation here:

https://docassemble.org/docs/background.html#background_response_choices

This does not update the label of the State field using JavaScript, however. You could write your own JavaScript to accomplish that somehow.

Another possibility would be to use the strategy described in this section to refresh the screen when a user changes the country:

https://docassemble.org/docs/background.html#background_response_refresh